# When using DB-API substitution for the column name in select query I don't get the expected value but column name instead

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am using Python 3.6 and sqlite3 for my project and for some reason unknown to me when using "?" for substitution of the column name I don't get the value in SELECT query, but instead I get column name as return.

I will provide some queries (database is really simple) and how I use substitution in the code:

```
#this woks without any issues
c.execute('SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE Name=?', (data,))

#I have an issue with this
c.execute('SELECT ? FROM Items WHERE Name=?', (column_name, data))
```

In the second query expected return is the value from the column, but instead I get tuple which contains column name instead of the value.

```
c.fetchone()
#expected return is (2,)
#return which I get is ('Sensor_value',) where 'Sensor_value' is column name

c.fetchall()
#return is [('Sensor_value',)] if someone needed that info
```

I am aware that I can use string manipulation for this, but I would like to know why this doesn't work although it is the most intuitive way of dealing with it.

Temporarily I am using the following code to bypass this issue so I am not looking into similar solutions:

```
c.execute('SELECT {col} FROM Items WHERE Name={na}'\
          .format(col=column_name, na=data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database prepared statement APIs do not allow the column or table name to be an input parameter.  Allowing for this would be a potentially large security breach, because then the outside caller could potentially execute SQL against any table or column in the entire database.  A workaround here would be to just have an if else statement which makes the appropriate call to `execute`, using the right column:

```
if column_name == "Sensor_value":
    c.execute('SELECT Sensor_value FROM Items WHERE Name = ?', (data,))
elif column_name == "Sensor_data":
    c.execute('SELECT Sensor_data FROM Items WHERE Name = ?', (data,))
else:
    c.execute('SELECT other FROM Items WHERE Name = ?', (data,))
```

This way, you ensure that only supported columns can be used in the query.  The problem with you temporary bypass is that, again, it allows the caller to potentially select any column in the table.  As an example to see why you would not want this, imagine a user table, which contains sensitive information in one column.  To access that column, all any outside caller has to do is just mention that column name.